# How to filter list based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, list

I have the following lists:

```
target_list = ["FOLD/AAA.RST.TXT"]
```

and

```
mylist = 
[
  "FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT",
  "FOLD/BBB.RST.12345.TXT",
  "RUNS/AAA.FGT.12345.TXT",
  "FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT",
  "RUNS/AAA.RST.11111.TXT"
]
```

How can I filter only those records of `mylist` that correspond to `target_list`? The expected result is:

```
  "FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT"
  "FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT"
```

The following mask is considered for filtering `mylist`

```
xxx/yyy.zzz.nnn.txt
```

If `xxx`, `yyy` and `zzz` coincide with `target_list`, then the record should be selected. Otherwise it should be dropped from the result.

How can I solve this task withou using for loop?

```
selected_list = []
for t in target_list:
   r1 = l.split("/")[0]
   a1 = l.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]
   b1 = l.split("/")[1].split(".")[1]

   for l in mylist:
      r2 = l.split("/")[0]
      a2 = l.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]
      b2 = l.split("/")[1].split(".")[1]

      if (r1==r2) & (a1==a2) & (b1==b2):
         selected_list.append(l)
```

Comment: ok, post your code

Comment: Why can’t you use a for loop?  Is a list comprehension acceptable to you?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: Please see my code. Not sure why it is needed here, if I am searching for a different solution. Do you want to check if I did a homework?:)

Comment: @NicholasM: Please see my code. It looks terrible in my opinion. I am searching for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a loop? Do you want to declare the pattern, and filter the results?

Comment: @PeterWood: Yes, I would prefer to use patterns. The thing is that my lists might be long. A nested for loop looks very ugly to me.

Comment: @Fluxy, as for "Not sure why it is needed here" read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions (section **Asking about homework**)

Comment: @Fluxy will the `nnn` part always be numbers? Are you okay with using regular expressions?

Comment: @pault: Yes, it is always a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a "filter-making function" that preprocesses the target list.  The advantages of this are:

- Does minimal work by caching information about `target_list` in a set:  The total time is `O(N_target_list) + O(N)`, since set lookups are O(1) on average.
- Does not use global variables. Easily testable.
- Does not use nested for loops

```
def prefixes(target):
    """ 
    >>> prefixes("FOLD/AAA.RST.TXT")
    ('FOLD', 'AAA', 'RST')

    >>> prefixes("FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT")
    ('FOLD', 'AAA', 'RST')
    """
    x, rest = target.split('/')
    y, z, *_ = rest.split('.')
    return x, y, z

def matcher(target_list):
    targets = set(prefixes(target) for target in target_list)
    def is_target(t):
        return prefixes(t) in targets
    return is_target
```

Then, you could do:

```
>>> list(filter(matcher(target_list), mylist))
['FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT', 'FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to filter values:

```
target_list = ["FOLD/AAA.RST.TXT"]

def keep(path):
    template = get_template(path)
    return template in target_list

def get_template(path):
    front, numbers, ext = path.rsplit('.', 2)
    template = '.'.join([front, ext])
    return template
```

This uses [**`str.rsplit`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) which searches the string in reverse and splits it on the given character, `.` in this case. The parameter `2` means it only performs at most two splits. This gives us three parts, the front, the numbers, and the extension:

```
>>> 'FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT'.rsplit('.', 2)
['FOLD/AAA.RST', '12345', 'TXT']
```

We assign these to `front`, `numbers` and `ext`.

We then build a string again using [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> '.'.join(['FOLD/AAA.RST', 'TXT']
'FOLD/AAA.RST.TXT'
```

So this is what `get_template` returns:

```
>>> get_template('FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT')
'FOLD/AAA.RST.TXT'
```

We can use it like so:

```
mylist = [
    "FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT",
    "FOLD/BBB.RST.12345.TXT",
    "RUNS/AAA.FGT.12345.TXT",
    "FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT",
    "RUNS/AAA.RST.11111.TXT"
]

from pprint import pprint

pprint(filter(keep, mylist))
```

Output:

```
['FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT'
 'FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT']
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please comment `keep` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to define a pattern, and check if your strings match that pattern.

In this case, split the `target` and insert a `\d+` in between the `xxx/yyy.zzz.` and the `.txt` part. Use this as the pattern.

The pattern `\d+` means any number of digits. The rest of the pattern will be created based on the literal values of `xxx/yyy.zzz` and `.txt`. Since the period has a special meaning in regular expressions, we have to escape it with a `\`.

```
import re

selected_list = []
for target in target_list:
    base, ext = target.rsplit(".", 1)
    pat = ".".join([base, "\d+", ext] ).replace(".", "\.")
    selected_list.append([s for s in mylist if re.match(pat, s) is not None])
print(selected_list)
#[['FOLD/AAA.RST.12345.TXT', 'FOLD/AAA.RST.87589.TXT']]
```

If the pattern does not match, `re.match` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `filter` + `lambda` function:

```
import re
result=list(filter(lambda item: re.sub(r'.[0-9]+', '', item) == target_list[0], mylist))
```

Some comments:

- The approach is to exclude digits from the comparison.  So in the
  `lambda` function, for each mylist item we replace digits with '',
  then compare against the only item in target_list, target_list[0].
- `filter` will match all items where the lambda function is `True`
- Wrap everything in `list` to convert from `filter` object to `list`
  object